# Return result from a constructor from another class in java

Tags: java

Here is the first file and there is another to follow, to really explain my question; my question starts in the `public Account getbankAddress()` method.

```
public class Bank {

    String bankName;
    int bankID;
    Address address = new Address();

    public Bank(){
        bankName = "?";
        bankID = 0;
    }

    public String getBankName(){
        return bankName;
    }

    public int getBankID(){
        return bankID;
    }

    public Address getBankAddress(){ 
        // This is where I'm having trouble getting the bank address from the address class,
        // How can I produce a result from the mutator method of setCity and setState methods?
        return address;
    }

    public void setBankName(String bankName1){
        bankName = bankName1;
    }

    public void setBankID(int ID){
        bankID = ID;
    }

    public void setBankAddress(String aCity, String aState){
        aCity = "city";
        aState = "state";
    }

    public String toString(){
        String str = ("\nBank name:\t\t" + bankName + "\nBank ID:\t\t" + bankID +
                "\nBank address:\t\t" + bankAddress + "\n\n");
        return str;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Address{

    private String city;
    private String state;

    public Address(){
        city = "?";
        state = "?";
    }

    public String getCity(){
        return city;
    }

    public String getState(){
        return state;
    }

    public void setCity(String aCity){
        aCity = city;
    }

    public void setState(String aState){
        aState = state;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String str1 = (city + "," + state);
        return str1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: You have the assignments wrong. Should be `city=aCity`, not the other way around.

Comment: Can you explain what is your problem in words not in code.

Comment: Thank you guys for looking at this, the code below solved the error

Answer (score 6):

I think changing this:

```
public void setBankAddress(String aCity, String aState){

aCity = "city";
aState = "state";

 }
```

to

```
public void setBankAddress(String aCity, String aState) {
  address.setCity(aCity);
  address.setState(aState);
}
```

should work.

++++++++++++++++

Also, change this:

```
public void setCity(String aCity){
    aCity = city;
}

public void setState(String aState){
    aState = state;
}
```

to

```
public void setCity(String aCity){
    city = aCity;
}

public void setState(String aState){
    state = aState;
}
```